# Can I share my tarsnap key file between machines?

Tags: tarsnap

I have a set of archives built from one server. As we are planning to move to another server, can I just bring that tarsnap key over to my new machine to use there? I'm not sure about the semantics of the tarsnap key; I understand it's use to encrypt and decrypt my tarsnap archives but it's not clear to me if it's tied to a specific machine/IP address.

Comment: Your IP address is not used to encrypt or decrypt your data

Comment: You might read how this service works the fact it's able to detect duplicate data exists is concerning from a security stand point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A key is tied to a particular archive, so [you can reuse a key file from another machine](http://mail.tarsnap.com/tarsnap-users/msg00428.html), but you probably [don't want to share a key between two machines that are archiving.](http://mail.tarsnap.com/tarsnap-users/msg00533.html)